# TS2307: error module not found local geojson in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I want to draw a world map using d3-geo-projection. As input file I've thus far used https://enjalot.github.io/wwsd/data/world/world-110m.geojson, but I want to switch to a locally hosted version of that exact file.

Code I'm using that works fine:

```js
const url = "https://enjalot.github.io/wwsd/data/world/world-110m.geojson";
d3.json(url).then(function(geojson) {
  svg.append("path").attr("d", path(geojson))
});
```

Using examples and tutorials, I've added `import world110m from './world110m.geojson';` with world110m.geojson in the same folder as the file, and changed `const url"...";` to `const url = world110m;`.

This results in 2 errors in Terminal:

> ERROR in ./src/app/02_robinson_projection/world110m.geojson 1:7
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders 
>   are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>   {"type":"Fea...

and

> ERROR in src/app/02_robinson_projection/robinson-projection.component.ts(5,23): error TS2307: Cannot find module './world110m.geojson'.

Some googling resulted in having to add:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "resolveJsonModule": true, 
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  ...
}
```

However, the errors stay and the page in the browser gets a black overlay giving the first error.

I've looked in integrating webpack further in my project (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/), but when I look for a geojson-loader all I find is the old json-loader, which I've included instead (even though it says it's not necessary any more).
Together with this I also created a webpack.config.js,

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.geojson$/, use: 'json-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

But I'm quite sure this code is incorrect.

I know it's comparing apples to oranges, but why is including a local (geo)json file in Angular such a hassle? When I try above in plain JS with a local geojson it works just fine.